# error while working with Makefile project

Tags: cmake, clion

I am trying to debug my `Makefile` based project which I have imported in `CLion`. I created a simple `CMake` file as below

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(Project1)

set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ")

add_custom_target(myProject COMMAND make -j4 DEBUG=1
    CLION_EXE_DIR=${PACKAGE_DIR})
```

`CMake` tool shows me error: `CMake executable not specified`. I tried adding `add_executable(myProject ${SOURCE_FILES})` with correct source files, but still same error.

Where as on `Edit Configurations` page, I cannot select any Configuration. The drop down for Configuration is empty. At the bottom I get error `Error: Configuration is not specified.`.

When I try to debug the program, I get a warning message `Configuration is still incorrect. Do you want to edit it again?` I click on Continue Anyway, which compiles the program as I expect and it generates the correct executable file as well. But it cannot run the executable because of the errors in the Configurations.

Comment: I assume "CMake executable" refers to the location of the executable `cmake` which is called to configure your project. Probably you have to search for a setting in CLion where you can define /usr/bin/cmake or whereever your cmake resides.

Comment: that was correct. Thanks. I was pointing to incorrect cmake. All the time I kept thinking about `target` of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume "CMake executable" refers to the location of the executable cmake which is called to configure your project. Probably you have to search for a setting in CLion where you can define /usr/bin/cmake or whereever your cmake resides.

Comment: setting is available in toolchains.

Comment: For ubuntu:  sudo apt-get install cmake

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me (Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```